# Html input control for passwords - not showing no of characters typed or showing spaces instead of dots

Tags: asp.net, html, security, input, passwords

Is is possible to use the password element in html input type="password" in a mode whereby one dosn't show the characters types as asterixes/circles but as spaces/nothing so noone would know the length of the password.

Comment: That would confuse so many less-computer-literate users. (People already complain that 'ssh' or PuTTY "don't accept passwords".)

Comment: I can see how this could be confusing, but it's a immovable requirement so I guess some training will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you make the text color the same as the background? (Haven't tried it myself....)

Answer (score 0):

In theory:

```
some-selector {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

The selector could be `input[type=password]` if you don't care about browsers that don't support attribute selectors (i.e. older versions of IE)